# compute expectation

Tags: probability, integration

I would like to simplify the following double integral expression:

$\int q(z_1|x) (\int q(z_2|z_1) \log q(z_1|x) dz_2) dz_1$

Originally, they are expectation terms:

$E_{q(z_1|x)}[ E_{q(z_2|z_1)} \log q(z_1|x)]]$

What I deduct from my own calculation is that I cannot simplify this any further. For example, there is no constant term that I can easily move it out of the expectation. Is this correct?

Basically, I think $\int q(z_2|z_1) \log q(z_1|x) dz_2 \ne \log q(z_1|x)$. Can someone please double confirm this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems like it depends on what $q$ is. In particular, in $\int q(z_2|z_1) \log q(z_1 \mid x) dz_2$, you can pull the log out of the integration because it does not depend on $z_2$. So your inequality amounts to saying $\int q(z_2 \mid z_1) dz_2 \neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I am glad I asked.